# vector of pointers or structs?

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, struct

Say, I define a struct (or class, doesn't matter) called `Node`. In C++, we can either use a vector of structs or vector of pointers to store many `Node`s.

```
struct Node {...}
void main() {
    std::vector<Node> nodes;
    // or we can write:
    std::vector<Node*> nodes;
}
```

As far as I've learnt, if I use vector of structs, then the vector need a large memory to store every whole struct inside the vector. So I think vector of pointers is better. But now I'm thinking that, is there any grammar I don't know, or any roundabout method to write `vector<Node>` while not copying every struct inside the vector? Or even better, maybe the compiler already does this optimization for me?

Comment: Prefer `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>>` instead of `std::vector<Node*>` when the vector owns its objects, which is the case if it is being used as an alternative to `std::vector<Node>`. `std::vector<Node>` can be fine, depending on the expected number of `Node` objects and its size.

Comment: If there's a large number of `Node`s, they have to exist somewhere. A pointer has to point to something. Using a vector of pointers to objects, instead of the objects themselves, does not change that. Having said that, reallocating a vector of small pointers, versus a vector large objects, certainly makes a difference. But you have to fully understand what the implications are, specifically in terms of object lifetimes. Otherwise, you end up leaking memory everywhere, and a lot of good that will do.

Comment: Using g++ 9.3.0 on Ubuntu 20.04,  a "std::vector<T>  tVec;"  occupies 24 bytes, regardless of the sizeof(T) and regardless of the number of elements (i.e. tVec.size()).  [note: some vector implementations differ.]   The implication is that the elements of tVec reside in heap, and std::vector takes care of the pointers and vector size growth. This means that the "large memory" used (for many large T's) is not on your system's stack.  Your use of pointers (or smart_ptrs) might be a waste of your time, and somewhat slower in operation.

Answer (score 4):

> if I use vector of structs, then the vector need a large memory to store every whole struct inside the vector.

No matter where or how you store them they will take up memory. The nodes have to be somewhere in memory right? Actually vector of pointers uses more memory overall because besides the memory for the actual nodes you need memory for the pointers.

vector of pointers have two well known **performance drawbacks**:

- indirection. Accessing an element means: first access the pointer from the vector, then access the element from the retrieved address.
- not cache friendly: when you iterate over a vector of nodes all nodes are adjacent and are brought in cache together. When you have a vector of pointers, each node can be anywhere in memory. An element will rarely be in cache and will be evicted more rapidly from cache.

Both of these are a big deal and will lead in most scenarios to a measurable performance hit. So a vector of pointer is almost never a good thing for performance.

Some other answers mention relocations. However this is not as bad as it might first seem. First of all relocations via [push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) are guaranteed to have an amortized constant complexity. And there are some easy ways to mitigate them even further, like reserving in advance. If rellocation are indeed a problem - determined with profiling - then a better alternative could be `std::list`.

There are some valid uses for vector of pointers like needing to store polymorphic objects. And if you use pointers then use smart pointers.